# SharePoint List Column deleted by user I need to know by whom

Tags: sharepoint-server, column

In Production one user has deleted the one column I need to know who has deleted the column.
Please Help to find the way how we can track.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as though you want to do this on something that's already happened. Unfortunately, unless you turned on auditing (which isn't automatic and which many people who even know about it don't use because it can sigificantly increase the size of your content database), the DB doesn't track this information on its own. Depending on how large your site is and how you're set up in Active Directory, you *might* be able to check with your IT admin as to who logged in and when to narrow things down a bit. That's beyond the scope of SharePoint though.

Comment: Thanks. Is auditing is available in SharePoint 2010 foundation? we are using SharePoint 2010 foundation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to enable the Auditing (in "Information management policy settings" under "Permissions and Management") of the list before you can track who delete the column.

[image]

Comment: I think the problem here is that the column has already been deleted

Answer (score 1):

We are using SharePoint foundation server.

Thanks for all your support.

I recreated the same name and type column again.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways you can know who deleted your site columns. You can add you custom event receiver called Field Deleted on your list and write your custom logging according to your custom logic.

Other thing is that you can use sharepoint out of the box audit log reports feature to check the who deleted the field.
Also check: 
http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/view-audit-log-reports-HA102039795.aspx

Comment: I think the problem here is that the column has already been deleted

Comment: In that case they need to check audit logs, if they are enabled on the site. For the long run, they can enable these type of logging.